# Combine last name and initial of first name in excel - format of the word is "last name, first name" in single cell

Tags: excel-formula, basic

I want to create user Id using "Initials of first name.last name", the format of the word is "last name, first name" in single cell.

Column D - Smith, John

Result - J.Smith

I used = =PROPER(TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(D3," ",REPT(" ",99)),99))&"."&RIGHT(D3,(LEN(D3)-FIND(", ",D3)-1)))

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please considering editing your question to help any prospective answerers address your issue ([ask]). Also, use the `code` tags. Finally, please include information about how what you have tried is not working - what sort of results are you getting and are you getting any error messages?

Answer (score 3):

Try,

```
=MID(D3, FIND(",", D3&",  ")+2, 1)&". "&LEFT(D3, FIND(",", D3&",")-1)
```

[image]